# Solving simple LP problem with Lagrange multipliers

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Hi just as a test I'm trying to solve the following LP with Lagrange multipliers.

$min  -x_1$

$s.t$

$x_2 \leq 1 - x_1$

$x_1, x_2 \geq 0 $

I add slack variables to have a equality constrained LP

$min  -x_1$

$s.t$

$x_2 +x_1 +s_1 -1 =0$

$x_1 -s_2 =  0 $

$x_2 - s_3=0$

I then look at the gradients and find the following system

$-1 + \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 =0 $

$\lambda_1 + \lambda_3 =0 $

$\lambda_1 =0 $

$-\lambda_2 =0 $

$-\lambda_3 =0 $

This system is not consistent though, since it says $-1=0$

If this happens, that is there is no $\lambda_i$ such that the system is satisfied then the problem is unbounded. That is not the case though, since we see that the optimal of $x_1=1,x_2=0$ is optimal with objective value $-1$. I've messed something up here basic. Some feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need $s_3$? Given $x_1+x_2+s_1-1=0$ and $x_1-s_2=0$ then you have $x_2+s_1+s_2-1=0$. And normally one begins with $\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g$ which would give $1+\lambda_1+\lambda_2=0$ instead of $-1+\lambda_1+\lambda_2=0$.

Comment: I've solved the problem via KKT conditions. Thanks for the tip, it got me to the point where i could figure it out.

Comment: @Vogster  Glad it helped.